# What does the Recurly API buildTransactionForm successURL uuid identify?

Tags: recurly

When using Recurly.buildTransactionForm, you can choose which page the user will be taken to after the payment succeeds. This is selected by the argument "successURL" when building the transaction form.

The the payer is taken to that successURL, some results will also get POSTed to the page. One of these is **uuid**.

But what does that UUID represent? I have been storing the UUIDs in the database just in case, and lately started trying to match them with different types of objects mentioned in the API.

I tried at least

```
recurly.Transaction.get(uuid) (not found)
recurly.Subscription.get(uuid) (not found)
recurly.Invoice.get(uuid) (not found)
recurly.Account.get(uuid) (not found)
recurly.Plan.get(uuid) (not found)
recurly.Adjustment.get(uuid) (not found)
```

It seemed most likely the uuid would be a transaction uuid, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I tried it by doing

```
 print recurly.Transaction.get(uuid)

 # result
 recurly.errors.NotFoundError: not_found: Couldn't find Transaction with uuid = ...
```

Comment: Is that the Python client?

Comment: I believe recurly.buildTransactionForm() is deprecated as it is part of Recurly v2. I would recommend checking out v3: https://docs.recurly.com/js/.

Comment: Also, what is the `recurly` object you are using? The `Recurly` object (note the capital 'R') contains a `Transaction` object, but the transaction object does not have a `get()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Before I delve in the meaning of UUID, I just want to bring to your attention that `recurly.buildTransactionForm()` is deprecated as it is part of Recurly v2. I would recommend checking out v3: [docs.recurly.com/js](http://docs.recurly.com/js).

> But what does that UUID represent?

UUID stands for "Universal Unique Identifier". You should be able to use the `uuid` value as a unique identifier for transactions and such.